# c#: Method expects type

Tags: c#

```
class Country
{
   //props
}
```

dataContext is a variable with a method Set(), which works fine like as below

```
dataContext.Set<Country>().SomeThing();
```

but  i dont want to hard code the **type=Country**, rather i want to extract type out from a variable eg

```
function MyFunction(object o)
{
   dataContext.Set</*something_here*/>().SomeThing();
   //some how extract type from variable o
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to hard code Country? Will it change? In what way will it change? How will it change? In your example, `o` isn't even of type `Country`, so it's not like changing the type of `o` should in any way change the type parameter of the `Set` method.

Comment: Did we fix your problem?

Comment: Can you accept an answer if we solved your problem?

Comment: your answer didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
void MyFunction<T> (T o)
{
    dataContext.Set<T> ().SomeThing ();
}
```

Then call it with:

```
MyFunction<County> (county_object);
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `MyFunction(country_object);`.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: MyFunction<County> (county_object); // at this time i only have country_object, how can i hard code 'County' in "MyFunction<County>"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can do like Daniel suggested and drop the <County> from the function call or you can just type exactly what I suggested and it's hard coded.

Comment: @Praveen - the `Type` of `county_object` is implicit when you don't explicitly assign the generic type `County`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, you can do this with some reflection trickery. Basically, it's going to boil down like so:

1. Find the MethodInfo object for your set method.
2. `MakeGenericType` on that MethodInfo with the `o.GetType()`.
3. Invoke that method and then the `SomeThing` method.

Trying to code this from memory here, so please pardon any code errors:

```
 var setMethod = dataContext.GetType().GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Set");

 var genericVersion = setMethod.MakeGenericType(o.GetType());

 var result = genericVersion.Invoke(dataContext, null) as WhateverSetReturns;

 result.SomeThing();
```